# Why doesn't stopping animations and then starting a new fadeIn work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm fairly new to using JQuery and was just playing around. I'm trying to have an element fade in on the click of a button. If the users clicks the button again, while the element is still fading in, I want it to start hidden/invisible again. So I first stop all animations `stop(true)` then hide the element an let it fade in.

I can't get it to work though. It seems like the second fade in starts with the opacity the element has at that moment and fades in from there. I've also tried to use `css("opacity", 0)` in stead of `hide()` but then the element just gets it's opacity set to 0 and fadeIn doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("button").click(function () {
                    $("span").stop(true).hide().fadeIn(3000);
                });
            })
        </script>
        <button>FadeIn</button> <span>Hello, world!</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using JQuery 1.7.2 and tried in Chrome and IE.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're new to jQuery, then pay close attention to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: @Sparky672: I did read the documentation for `stop`. Actually `stop` _does_ seem to work. The problem is more that the `fadeIn` doesn't start with an opacity of 0 again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.stop(true)` just stops the animation and leaves it wherever it was.  If you were in the middle of a `fade()`, then the object will be left with an opacity value in the middle of the fade.

If you want to stop the animation and put the opacity in a known state, then you probably just want to set it to what you want it to start at.  `.hide()` sets `display: none` - it doesn't mess with the opacity.

So, if you were in the middle of a `fadeOut()` when you did the `.stop(true)`, then you could just do `.stop(true, true)` and that will jump the current animation to the end, thus giving you a good place to start your `fadeIn()` from.

You could also stop the animation where it was and then fade from there to your full opacity with:

```
.stop(true).fadeTo(3000, 1);
```

which is more generally what you want to do when you're interrupting the previous animation.

Comment: I can understand why `hide()` won't work. But then why doesn't `css("opacity", 0)` work?

Comment: I believe `fadeIn()` assumes the object is display: none, with the desired finished opacity set on it.  The idea is to fade it in to the currently set opacity.

Comment: If you really want to reset it for a full `fadeIn()` animation, you would do this: `.stop(true).hide().css("opacity", 1).fadeIn(2000);`

Comment: You are right. The JQuery documentation doesn't explicitly say that, but indeed `fadeIn()` fades to the set opacity.

Comment: @comecme - yeah, I had to build a little test jsFiddle to verify it because the doc does not describe how this behavior is supposed to work.  I guess most people just start with a clean object of `display: none` and `opacity: 1` and never run into this issue.

Comment: If I would want the end result to be the opacity defined in the css, I couldn't use `fadeTo`. So ultimately I think `.stop(true).fadeOut(0).fadeIn(2000)` or `.stop(true, true).hide().fadeIn(2000)` are the best options then. The first option will set opacity to 0 immediately, while the second one will set it to the original value. You won't be able to see that as it is hidden immediately afterwards. Hiding it first may even be better: `.hide().stop(true,true).fadeIn(2000)`. But I think I'll go for the fadeOut + fadeIn combination.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a second `true` to `"jump to the end"`:

`.stop(true,true)`

http://jsfiddle.net/V8wRE/2/

Comment: Wouldn't that actually set opacity to 1 first and _then_ start over? Not that I'd be able to see it happen I think. Any idea on _why_ I'd have to jump to the end first?

Comment: @micha: According to the documentation `stop()` will stop the current animation. Adding a `true` parameter will _also_ clear the queue. Or do you mean that `stop` will actually pause the animation, making it continue when a new animation starts?

Comment: @comecme The end phase of fadeIn is just `display: block*`, with no opacity value (which means fully opaque). The end phase of fadeOut/hide is just `display: none`. So don't mess with the opacity manually. This will do exactly what you wanted. * *Assuming the element is originally a block element*

Comment: No, the endfase of fadeIn is `display: block` with the opacity value it had originally. If you perform a fadeIn on `<span style="display: none; opacity: 0.5">Foo</span>` it will end with an opacity of 0.5 [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stuE6/1/). That's why I think using `.stop(true, true)` will first make the element visible.

Comment: @comecme That's what I mean by messing with opacity manually. It doesn't matter if it sets the element visible as you are calling hide next, which hides the element so that it can fade in. It will be the net effect because they are called synchronously. Try: `$("body").hide().show().hide().show().hide().show()`, it won't do anything (except side effects such as scrolling the page to the top) because they are synchronous and the net effect is show and the body is already shown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you stop your span and the animation is not complete, the `fadeIn` function will fade your span to the last known opacity (which is not 1 since the animation wasn't complete), so you could pass a second true flag to the `stop` function as Esailija said, or you could use `fadeTo` instead of `fadeIn` :

```
 $("span").stop(true).hide().fadeTo(3000,1);
```

Working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/V8wRE/3/

Comment: Well, indeed it works, but again I wonder _why_. I'd expect `fadeTo` with an opacity `1` to be exactly the same as `fadeIn`. `fadeIn` fades to 1, `fadeTo` fades to specified opacity.

Comment: fadeIn will fade to the last known opacity which can be different from  1

Comment: If `fadeIn` fades to the last known opacity, then it would never reach `1`. But that's not what happens. It will reach `1` finally.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem earlier today but with fadeTo not fadeIn. I just used this code

```
$(news_controls).hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
},function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.4);
});
```

However as it has been said in your case two true flags are needed to jump to the end so your code should look like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("button").click(function () {
                    $("span").stop(true, true).hide().fadeIn(3000);
                });
            })
        </script>
        <button>FadeIn</button> <span>Hello, world!</span>
    </body>
</html>
```